# Issue with Freetype and OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, text, fonts, freetype

Hey, i'm having a weird issue with drawing text in openGL loaded with the Freetype 2 library. Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

[example http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/3316/freetypeweird.png](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/3316/freetypeweird.png)

Here are my code bits for loading and rendering my text.

```
class Font
{
    Font(const String& filename)
    {
       if (FT_New_Face(Font::ftLibrary, "arial.ttf", 0, &mFace)) {
          cout << "UH OH!" << endl;
       }

       FT_Set_Char_Size(mFace, 16 * 64, 16 * 64, 72, 72);
    }

    Glyph* GetGlyph(const unsigned char ch)
    {
       if(FT_Load_Char(mFace, ch, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
          cout << "OUCH" << endl;

       FT_Glyph glyph;

       if(FT_Get_Glyph( mFace->glyph, &glyph ))
          cout << "OUCH" << endl;

       FT_BitmapGlyph bitmap_glyph = (FT_BitmapGlyph)glyph;

       Glyph* thisGlyph = new Glyph;
       thisGlyph->buffer = bitmap_glyph->bitmap.buffer;
       thisGlyph->width = bitmap_glyph->bitmap.width;
       thisGlyph->height = bitmap_glyph->bitmap.rows;

       return thisGlyph;
    }
};
```

The relevant glyph information (width, height, buffer) is stored in the following struct

```
struct Glyph {
   GLubyte* buffer;
   Uint width;
   Uint height;
};
```

And finally, to render it, I have this class called RenderFont.

```
class RenderFont 
{
   RenderFont(Font* font)
   {
      mTextureIds = new GLuint[128];

      mFirstDisplayListId=glGenLists(128);
      glGenTextures( 128, mTextureIds );

      for(unsigned char i=0;i<128;i++)
      {
         MakeDisplayList(font, i);
      }
   }

   void MakeDisplayList(Font* font, unsigned char ch)
   {
      Glyph* glyph = font->GetGlyph(ch);

      glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIds[ch]);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
      glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

      glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                   0, 
                   GL_RGBA, 
                   glyph->width, 
                   glyph->height, 
                   0,
                   GL_ALPHA, 
                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                   glyph->buffer);

      glNewList(mFirstDisplayListId+ch,GL_COMPILE);
      glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureIds[ch]);

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      glTexCoord2d(0,1); glVertex2f(0,glyph->height);
      glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex2f(0,0);
      glTexCoord2d(1,0); glVertex2f(glyph->width,0);
      glTexCoord2d(1,1); glVertex2f(glyph->width,glyph->height);
      glEnd();

      glTranslatef(16, 0, 0);

      glEndList();
   }

   void Draw(const String& text, Uint size, const TransformComponent* transform, const Color32* color)
   {
      glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
      glEnable(GL_BLEND);
      glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

      glTranslatef(100, 250, 0.0f);

      glListBase(mFirstDisplayListId);

      glCallLists(text.length(), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, text.c_str());

      glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
      glDisable(GL_BLEND);

      glLoadIdentity();
   }

private:
   GLuint mFirstDisplayListId;
   GLuint* mTextureIds;
};
```

Can anybody see anything weird going on here that would cause the garbled text? It's strange because if I change the font size, or the DPI, then some of the letters that display correctly become garbled, and other letters that were garbled before then display correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not familiar with FreeType, but from the picture, it looks like the width of the characters is not directly related to the size of the buffers (ie. glyph->buffer does not point to an array of glyph->width*glyth->height bytes).

As a guess, I'd say that all the chars have a single width in memory (as opposed to the size they use on screen), probably the biggest of all the widths of the glyphs, but you load them with a per-char width instead of the correct one. So, only the glyphs that use the full width are correct.

Comment: This was the problem. I copied everything into a new buffer that was a set size padding it with empty pixels and everything worked properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```

This annoyed the heck out of me too, but you need to tell OpenGL to use the spacing you give it, not the normal 32-bit boundaries it expects.  The pitch of the images changes, but `OpenGL` doesn't know to use smaller packing alignments without these calls before your texture creation.

I do it like this:

```
// Convert the glyph to a bitmap.
FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap(&glyph, FT_RENDER_MODE_NORMAL, NULL, true);
FT_BitmapGlyph bitmap_glyph = (FT_BitmapGlyph)glyph;

// This reference will make accessing the bitmap easier
FT_Bitmap& bitmap = bitmap_glyph->bitmap;

int _Left = abs(bitmap_glyph->left);
int _Top = abs(bitmap_glyph->top);
int _Height = abs(bitmap.rows);
int _Width = _Left+abs(bitmap.width);

// If it's not a glyph or spacing, go to the next one
if ((_Width == 0 || _Height == 0) && !isspace(i))
    return;

advances[i] = max(_Width, face->glyph->advance.x >> 6);

vector<unsigned char> Data(_Height*_Width*2, 0);
for (int32 h=0; h < abs(bitmap.rows); ++h)
    for (int32 w=0; w < abs(bitmap.width); ++w)
    {
        int32 luminance = bitmap.buffer[h*bitmap.pitch + w];
        Data[(h*_Width + w + _Left)*2 + 0] = 255;
        Data[(h*_Width + w + _Left)*2 + 1] = luminance;
    }
```

I could probably move the 255 (White) into the String initialization function then just use the values in `FreeType` for my alpha values, but this way seems more descriptive and speed isn't an issue in my usage.

The Address &Data[0] now contains a `GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA external` format, with type `GL_UNSIGNED_CHAR` and size `_Width*_Height`.  This should make anyone who does this stuff's life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the `FT_Glyph` is actually a bitmap glyph? Make sure you use [`FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap`](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-glyph_management.html#FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap) first.

Alternatively, since you don't seem to need to store the `FT_Glyph`s around afterwards, you can just do:

```
int error = FT_Load_Char(face, ch, FT_LOAD_RENDER);
if(error)
   return error;

FT_GlyphSlot slot = face->glyph;
FT_Bitmap bitmap = slot->bitmap;

// do stuff with this FT_Bitmap
```

See [here](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-basic_types.html#FT_Bitmap) for the docs on `FT_Bitmap`. Just note that the next time you call `FT_Load_Char`, the data in `bitmap` will no longer be valid.

You also have a number of issues with memory management.

1. You use `new Glyph` to allocate your glyphs, but never call `delete.` Since you just need to temporarily make a glyph to generate the texture and display list, you should use an `std::auto_ptr<Glyph>`.
2. You never call `FT_Glyph_Done`, so all those `FT_Glyph`s you allocated are never released.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the memory management. I stripped all of that code out just for testing purposes to make sure my data wasn't getting accidentally deleted by accident when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score -1):

"16" should be the size of font in points. So, while translating you should use glyph->width instead of "16". Moreover, some letters may require kerning for best-looking texts. For example "AV" may look like "A V" without kerning usage.